# Ajax Login Response Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm traying to login with ajax and php, in that situation i'm logging succesfuly actually. But i'm trying to make an alert and refresh the page when logged in.
When i attempt to login, its gives me error and no refreshing. But if i refresh the page, i see i have session in php. I don't understand why.

Here is my code;

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#login_btn').click(function(){  
       var email = $('#email').val();  
       var password = $('#password').val();  


      if(email == '' || password == ''){
        $("#login_error").html("*** Please enter your email / password");
      }else{              
          $('#login_error').html("<strong class='text-success'>Validating...</strong>");

                $.ajax({
                url: "login.php",
                method: "post",
                data:{email:email, password:password},
                success: function(data){
                if (data === 'yes') {
                    window.location.reload();
                }else{
                    $('#login_error').html("<strong class='text-danger'>ERROR...</strong>");
                }
            }
                });

      }
    });
 }); 
</script>
```

login php:

```
<?php  
session_start();
include ('../config/setup.php'); #database connection


if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' AND password = '$_POST[password]'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    echo "yes";
}else{
    echo "no";
}
}
?>
```

Html: (Using login form inside a modal)

```
<div class="modal-body">

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Account Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Account Password" >
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">   
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
     <div align="center" class="col-sm-10">
      <button name="login_btn" id="login_btn" class="btn btn-success btn-block text-center"><span id="loader_before" class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" aria-hidden="true"></span><i id="loader" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-x fa-fw"></i> Log in to Account</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>    
  </div>
</div>

<div align="center" class="container-fluid">   
<h6><a href="#"><strong class="text-danger">Forgot your password? Click here..</strong></a></h6>
</div>  
<h5><div id="login_error" class="text-warning"></div></h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your if block in response as below
`

```
if (data === 'yes') {
    alert("You message here!");
    window.location.reload();
}else{
    $('#login_error').html("<strong class='text-danger'>ERROR...</strong>");
}
```

`

Comment: Can you share the error, it will help me to resolve the issue. Also you can try below sql statement.

$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."' AND password = '".$_POST['password']."'";

Comment: Error is: I have a div, id is loggin error. In javascript, i'm using this div to show situations of logging attempt. When i try to login in, it gives me $('#login_error').html("<strong class='text-danger'>ERROR...</strong>");
And not refreshing the page (window.location.reload(); in ajax) i'm refreshing page and i see i've logged in correctly. I need to see my success div and after refresh the page if i log in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you call echo on php, it will write the value, but not return it. That's the problem.
You are not returning "yes" or "no" from login.php, you're just doing echo, which will only write the value but not return it to the caller. 
The ajax call is waiting for a response to process it with the 'success' callback. Since login.php is not returning anything, it will always fall into the else clause.
The solution is to change this on login.php

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0){
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    return "yes";
}else{
    return "no";
}
```

Comment: I've change echo to return; but its same. Beside; if its echo: in mozilla development tool xhr answer is yes. if i change echo to return; answer is null.

Comment: But interesting, its logging in. Not refreshing automaticly, i'm refreshing the page and session working

Comment: why don't you debug with mozilla development tool and try to see why if hxr answers a yes, you don't receive that data on success callback

Comment: yes i'm using mozilla development tool. in your code, return, xhr response is null. if i change it to echo, xhr response is yes/no